# Color shade technique

Tags: color, gradient, shadows, technique

Hey does anyone know how you can get this increasingly popular door shade technique that helps objects look 3d. (Im talking about the way the object with arrows pointed to it is made of of 2 shades of grey on the pixel scale to look rough)

[image: Image from coin website]

Comment: add a slight noise layer to it in photoshop over the gradient perhaps?  located under effects

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term 'door shade'. From what I see, that's what you'd call a 'gradient'. Most image editing software incorporates gradient tools in with the other color and fill tools.

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to GD! To get good answers, it would be good if you can edit your question and add some more information: what software are you using?

Comment: We have quite a few good questions about using gradients in different scenarios, if you are interested you could [take a look!](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gradient?sort=votes&pageSize=30)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's GRADIENT or BLEND tool which you can find in any graphic editing software.